# include gpt model to comment my code or data

Tags: artificial-intelligence, openai-api, generative

Found on youtube that you can import openai language models in your code so i tried it. As far as i can see it needs payment to use.

```
import openai

# Define your code snippet
code = """
def add(a, b):
    # This function adds two numbers
    return a + b
"""

# Use the GPT model to generate comments
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=f"Please comment on the following code:\n{code}",
    max_tokens=50,  # Adjust as needed
)

# Extract the generated comments
comments = response.choices[0].text

# Insert comments into your code
code_with_comments = code + "\n" + comments

# Print or save the updated code
print(code_with_comments)
```

Is there any other model that is for free and can be added to my code in order to comment results?

Comment: I think you get x amount of free tokens per month, so you need to sign up to create an account.  If you are just using the AI personally to get text for yourapp, you might be okay, but if you want to include the AI into your app, you will reach the threshold and need to buy tokens each month unless you have a very low user base.